# Struggling with PHP email and XAMPP server

Tags: php, xampp, windows-10

I'm working on a website, and I want to code a 'contact us' page where the user can email me about the website, if there are any problems with the websites that I would need to fix or improvments that could be made. Firstly, the code continued to show up on my page but I fixed that error :P now this error keeps on showing up on the webpage.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\CoderClub4Kids\send_form_email.php on line 84

Natuarally, I thought it was because I didn't have any `<html>` tags. So I added the html code but the error kept on showing up, but this time it was about the line the code ended on, so I know it's not just line 84. Could this be to do with the way I've opened and closed my PHP code?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "email@example.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

    function died($error) {
        //error code
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."User".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."User" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
<p>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</p>
```

My HTML code:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

(this is working as it should do by the way)
Just so you know:
I'm on a windows 10 OS
I'm running my code off of XAMPP and I've got apache and mySQL running

But what is the problem with my PHP, could you explain in detail?
I'd bethankful to anyone who helps me :)

Comment: You're missing a closing brace `}` for `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {`

Comment: Wow that was so simple, I'm actually kicking myself. Thank you :-)